# Fast way for spreading info from flat table to normalized tables in Microsoft Sql Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, bulkinsert

so we are facing this problems and we are trying to solve them as efficiently as possible:

1. import data(130+k rows) from excel file
2. load it in given table on Sql Server Database
3. Disperse(normalize) the data from that table into 6 others

So far we've managed to cope with the first 2 problems.
We access the data from the file with the help of Excel Data Reader library, bind and bulk insert the loaded data 
with EntityFramework.BulkInsert. So far the process is taking less than 2 min, for little over 130k rows, which is acceptable.
The big problem comes when we try to normalize the data in the table loaded on the server.
The Database contains previous information and must be operational during changes => no table locking.
Table has 130 columns and contains information dispersed into 6 tables. The main record keeps foreign keys of the other 5.
Other records might or might not be already present in the database. If they are present missing information is updated.
The tricky part for us is knowing the ID of the sub entities at the time of the insertion of the main entity. Insertion row by row would solve the problem but it would take too much time.
We would like to use some kind of bulk insert, but we're not sure how to keep the connection between the records. 
The database design is legacy and reorganising it is not an option. :)

Any ideas for tool, approach or advice on the matter is welcomed :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What level of Normalization?

Comment: No less than third normal form.

Comment: Not with EF. ORMs are completely unsuitable for ETL jobs. ETL though is pure data manipulation. Load the data into a staging table then execute queries to read the data you want and insert it into the target tables. Or use SSIS to read the data from the sources and operate on the stream of data on the fly, eg use the "Multicast" step to send one row to multiple tables, storing only the columns you need in each table. Key lookups can be performed using the 'Lookup' step

Comment: what version of SQL-Server?  if you can try https://normalisercomponent.codeplex.com/

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Not sure you can do it 'faster' (plus we don't know how fast it is) because you need to do insert/updates, and especially because you cannot just lock the tables. So a lot of it comes from server resources, database utilization and so on.